# Static Column kendo grid error

Tags: kendo-ui

When i load kendoGrid with column (have locked), it is error :((

[image]

```
$("#GS_ResultTab_GridDeloyment").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: JsonDataToKendoSource(src, null, 15),
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        columns: [cl1, cl2, cl8, cl10, cl3, cl4, cl5, cl6, cl9, cl7]
    });
```

dataSource: list json to kendoDatasource

columns: list columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using version Q3 2014 or newer, the `kendo.resize()` method should fix your problem:

Try add this under your grid definition method:

```
kendo.resize($("#GS_ResultTab_GridDeloyment"));
```

If it would not help you can also try use this method on grid dataBound event:

```
$("#GS_ResultTab_GridDeloyment").kendoGrid({
    ...
    dataBound: function(e) { kendo.resize(e.sender.element); }
});
```